# PHP MYSQL HighScores list not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name "scores"

```
+----+-------+-------+-------------------+
| id | score | level | username          |
+----+-------+-------+-------------------+
|  1 |    65 | one   | dustyrydberg      |
|  2 |    56 | one   | dustyrydberg      |
|  3 |    34 | one   | pointedshrill     |
|  4 |    50 | one   | witchrage         |
|  5 |    41 | one   | spacetimeken      |
|  6 |    44 | one   | harperhetton      |
|  7 |    65 | one   | witchrage         |
|  8 |    70 | one   | paladino          |
|  9 |    50 | one   | chimpanzer        |
| 10 |    22 | one   | yahooligan        |
| 11 |   672 | one   | blueCrow          |
| 12 |   120 | one   | sleepyDolphin     |
| 13 |    43 | one   | gothicNightingale |
| 14 |    22 | one   | phonyPuppy        |
| 15 |    23 | one   | phonyPuppy        |
| 16 |    24 | one   | phonyPuppy        |
| 17 |    31 | one   | darlingFairy      |
| 18 |    36 | one   | starkVoid         |
+----+-------+-------+-------------------+
```

I am trying to list the top 10 highscores without duplication of usernames. I am doing this using php and mysql. I have a functions.php file which includes the following function:

```
function find_all_scores() {
    global $connection;

    $query  = "SELECT MIN(score), username ";
    $query .= "FROM scores ";
    $query .= "GROUP BY username ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY MIN(score) ASC";
    $score_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($score_set);
    return $score_set;
 }
```

Which is called on in the all_highscores.php file

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>

<?php

  $score_set = find_all_scores();
  $ranking = 1;

?>

<?php $layout_context = "score"; ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="navigation">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div id="page">
      <?php echo message(); ?>
        <h2>Your Highscores</h2>
        <p>Here are <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["username"]); ?>'s best scores.</p>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Position</th>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Username</th>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Level</th>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Score</th>
          </tr>

        <?php while($score = mysqli_fetch_assoc($score_set)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $ranking; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($score["username"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($score["level"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($score["score"]); ?></td>
            <?php
             $ranking = $ranking + 1; /* INCREMENT RANKING BY 1 */
           ?>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>

        </table>

      </div>
    </div>

<?php
  // 4. Release returned data
  //mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

However I keep ending up with either a query failure or nothing displays in the HTML browser. Please help!

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you think that query would return the top 10 of anything!?!?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Also, aren't scores normally better when they're bigger?